# How do I move an element in my list to the end in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings called values and I want to make an element in the list to be the very last element. For example, if I have the string:

```
['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

I want string2 to be the very last element:

```
['string1', 'string3', 'string2']
```

There also may be an instance when my list does not contain string2. Is there an easy way to do this? This is what I have so far:

```
if 'string2' in values:
    for i in values:
        #remove string2 and append to end
```

Comment: What if there are multiple 'string2's?  Or are you talking about the second index?

Comment: there is only one string2. but my list is much bigger than the small example I'm giving. so I wont know the exact index

Comment: Do you care what happens to the element that WAS the last value? Can it be moved arbitrarily elsewhere in your list? Or do you need it to now be the second to last value?

Comment: the rest of the order doesn't matter. so the element that was the last value could be put anywhere

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
>>> lst = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
>>> lst.append(lst.pop(lst.index('string2')))
>>> lst
['string1', 'string3', 'string2']
```

We look for the index of `'string2'`, pop that index out of the list and then append it to the list.

Perhaps a somewhat more exception free way is to add the thing you're looking for to the end of the list first (after all, you already presumably know what it is).  Then delete the first instance of that string from the list:

```
>>> lst = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
>>> lst.append('string2')
>>> del lst[lst.index('string2')]  # Equivalent to lst.remove('string2')
>>> lst
['string1', 'string3', 'string2']
```

Comment: Even though the first method feels more pythonic, but I found the seconde one more readable.

Answer (score 22):

`sort` is O(n) for this operation<sup>†</sup>, so it's the same time complexity as the other answer without the 2 or 3 function lookups. There is no error if 'string2' isn't in the list

```
>>> lst = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
>>> lst.sort(key='string2'.__eq__)
>>> lst
['string1', 'string3', 'string2']
```

You can use this same trick to move all the "string2" to the end of the list. Or more generally an entire category eg to move everything starting with `string` to the end of the list:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda s:s.startswith('string'))
```

---

† Timsort sees this as a maximim of 3 "runs" and timsort is a stable sort

Answer (score 11):

```
lst = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
lst.append('string2')
lst.remove('string2')     # -> ['string1', 'string3', 'string2']
```

(mgilson made an excellent point - if you add the value to the list first, there will always be one to remove)

Comment: does the remove always remove the very first one it finds?

Comment: @RDoolabh -- Yes.  See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).  "Remove the **first** item from the list whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item."

Comment: looks really ugly. isn't there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Given your clarification, that you just want a select item pushed to the end, and you don't care where the afore-last-item ends up, I think the fastest thing is to find the index of your candidate value, and swap that with the end value. This avoids having to shuffle memory to from the remove(). I haven't timed it, but on big lists, it'd be faster (OTOH, if it's fast enough for you, you shouldn't care).

```
def pushToEnd(sequence, toBeLast):
    try:
        swapIndex = sequence.index(toBeLast)
    except ValueError:
        return
    sequence[-1], sequence[swapIndex] = sequence[swapIndex], sequence[-1]

fastCars = ['ferarri', 'porsche', 'bugatti', 'lamborghini', 'zonda', 'koenigsegg', 'mcclaren']
pushToEnd(fastCars, 'bugatti')
print(fastCars)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#move nth element to last
def movetolast(s, n):
    last = s.index(n)
    s[-1], s[last] = s[last], s[-1]
    return s
print(movetolast([2,3,4,6,7],3)) #[2, 7, 4, 6, 3]
print(movetolast(['apple','cherry','kiwi','mango'],'apple')) #['mango', 'cherry', 'kiwi', 'apple']
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler way with returning of new list:

```
movetolast = lambda l, e: [x for x in l if x != e] + [e]

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
movetolast(lst, 2)
```